# Logic foundation for formal verification

Tags: formal-methods, software-verification, linear-temporal-logic, hoare-logic

What types of logic should one study as foundation before diving into the area of software verification? What I can think of are:

1. Hoare Logic (for proving correctness of imperative programs)
2. Linear Temporal Logic (to model-check programs)

What can be others?

Answer (score 2):

It is helpful to know basic mathematics and logic.  But I would suggest that you go ahead and study software verification now, and learn additional logical background as needed.  There is an unending literature on logic that one could potentially learn, but I think better to learn it on demand.

Comment: On top of this, I would recommend getting a good modern proof assistant, like Lean or Coq, and just start playing with it. Prove some simple theorems that you already know. There is nothing quite like hands-on learning.

Comment: Thanks @Pseudonym. I know beginner level Haskell. Which proof assistant would suit me the most? I tried to explore Coq but the learning curve seemed very steep.

Comment: I mean an _interactive_ proof assistant!

Comment: @a_fan I don't know, but consider signing up for this new beta SE: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants